# Issue with mongodb install on Mac

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have mongodb running in one terminal window and now in another I get this error when I run server.js (a file from an online Mean class I'm taking):

> Daves-MB-Retina-Oct2014:mean Dave$ node server.js module.js:338
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>       at require (module.js:384:17)
>       at Object.          (/Users/.../.../udemy/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb
>
> ```
>   native/objectid.js:8:16)
> at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
> at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
> at require (module.js:384:17)
> ```
>
> MongoDB is in another directory.  Does that matter?  I did a npm
>   update in the directory I was in and nothing updates.  Here is what is
>   in the directory: Daves-MB-Retina-Oct2014:mean Dave$ ls
>   Gruntfile.js      bower_components    package.json
>   LICENSE           config          packages Procfile       karma.conf.js       server.js
>   README.md     mean.json       tools bower.json        node_modules

Comment: Mongodb can be running anywhere. This issue is probably due to an unsuccessful `npm install`. Try deleting the node_modules directory, and running npm install again

Comment: Just tried that.  It did not work.  Got a bunch of errors.  Probably too many to paste in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received help outside of Stackoverflow to solve this.  I reinstalled everything in a new directory and did npm install in a few subdirectories where the install script failed.  All set now.